# Loan up to 22k, what to do?

Tags: investing, loans, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies

I am a student who recently started working and have a salary of roughly 1.2k euros per month, most of which goes to savings because I live with my parents. Due to my salary, my bank offers me a loan of up to 22k euros. I feel that I can use that loan to get more money but I'm not sure what to do/what to invest. What should I do with such loan? If its of interest I live in Spain and I'm 24 years old.

Comment: If there's a way to take the 22k euros and invest it to make more money, why doesn't the bank just do that?

Comment: (1) Get a weekend job - at least 20 hours. Any job.  (2) If relevant to your field, and it is not expensive, do some sort of further education degree, say three nights a week.  (3) The other three weeknights, get another extra job.  (4) Look for ways to cut your expenses.  (5) Consider getting married - as a general rule, married family units are just more successful financially.  (Regarding the bank offer you mention, forget it - throw it in the bin like any other junk mail.)

Comment: @DJohnM That's stretching it a bit far.  Taking your sentiment to the extreme would imply that banks would always directly invest their money and would never loan money to anyone.

Answer (score 10):

Learn early that you can't borrow or spend your way to financial success. Plan for bad stuff to happen,  and be pleasantly surprised when it doesn't. Once you have 6 months living expenses set aside (not borrowed),  build up a 10k starter investment fund (not borrowed). Roll that into a low turnover small cap mutual fund while you study and determine the mix that is right for you.

In case you missed it,  don't borrow to start investing.

Answer (score 4):

If you have to think about what to do with the money, then you don't need it and therefore you should not take the loan; i.e. you should do nothing. As your credit worthiness and income increases, you should get used to banks offering to loan you money. In general, the reason they keep offering is because you are good at saying no to them. If you were to suddenly start accepting their money, eventually the offers will slow down, and their terms will be less desirable. As a rule of thumb, don't borrow money unless you actually need it. The exception to this is a 0% rate and 0% fee. If you take a loan with zero-zero terms and don't know what you'll do with it, at least you don't lose anything if you decide to do nothing and just pay it back.